# How to change a BoundField's control in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Can you change a BoundField's Control?

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="week1" HeaderText="week1" SortExpression="beginDate" />
```

Comment: Change what specifically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't change the control that's created when you use a BoundField - that's chosen automatically based on the data type of the field you're binding to (a CheckBox gets created for boolean fields, a Label for text-type fields).

You need to use a [TemplateField](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.aspx) if you want to bind your data to a different type of control:

```
<asp:templatefield headertext="week1">
    <itemtemplate>
        <asp:label id="weekOneLbl" Text= '<%# Eval("week1") %>' runat="server"/>
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```

By default, your BoundField will use a Label control (like above).  But with the TemplateField, you could change it to, say, a read-only TextBox:

```
<asp:templatefield headertext="week1">
    <itemtemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="weekOneLbl" Text= '<%# Eval("week1") %>' runat="server" ReadOnly="True" />
    </itemtemplate>
</asp:templatefield>
```